# US State tax rates APIs?

Tags: api

Is there an API, free or paid, that offer USA States tax rates in http request format?

I know each state website will carry this information but I need tax rates for all 50 states that I would like to use on my project.

Broadening the questions...

Is there any database out there, free or paid, that has any sort of tax rate information??

Comment: Which tax, on what property or sale or income? As with anything legal, this can be a maze of exceptions... and there may be local taxes as well as state and/or federal taxes.

Comment: I would like all of them :) but just trying to find out the best way to get any state tax information.  Income to start would be great.  I think worldbank offers API for some fantastic information.  Wish government would do something similar with tax information... And another wish for turbotax to share their tax rate data..

Comment: I doubt there would an *API* for this, as after all it's not data that's likely to change very often or quickly.

Comment: Although eat my own words: http://www.zip-tax.com/ =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to inform others...  Here is an api that you can retrieve state individual income tax rates in json.  It may help...

http://www.taxee.io/

I'm not affiliated with taxee.io

Comment: Looks like taxee.io can't afford to buy SSL certificate.

Comment: @JhourladEstrella here is their GH https://github.com/taxee/taxee-tax-statistics

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, their most recent tax stat is 2020. Looks like the project has been abandoned.